# Using tr to replace text with repeated characters

Tags: text-processing, tr

I tried using `tr` to replace a variable name in a file, and I noticed some behavior I can't figure out if the variable has a repeated character.

For example:

```
echo "aab" | tr 'aab' 'xyz'
```

gives the result 'yyz' when I was expecting xyz.

Can anyone explain what is happening here?

I'm aware that I can use other commands like `sed` to achieve the result I want, but I'm curious to understand what `tr` is doing is this situation.  I've looked at the man page and haven't found any other explanation of why this would happen.  Thanks

Comment: Considering that NONE of `man` pages for base tools contain any examples whatsoever, the downvote is nothing short of trolling. Why is this resource so obsessed with downvoting?

Comment: @ajeh: Manual pages are concise references. They are not tutorials, and they are not intended to be used as tutorials.

Comment: If you want to replace "aab" with "xyz", sed is a better tool: `sed 's/aab/xyz/g' file`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`tr` processes individual characters, not strings of characters. Its arguments are sets of characters, constituting a one-to-one mapping:

```
tr aab xyz
```

means “replace `a` with `x`, `a` with `y`, `b` with `z`”. It might help to view the two sets one above the other:

```
tr aab \
   xyz
```

If the second set is shorter than the first, it is extended by repeating the last character (by default). The sets are read in order, not applied in order; so the “`a` → `y`” replacement above erases the “`a` → `x`” replacement defined just prior.