# I cannot understand what -c parameter does in tr command in Ubuntu GNU/Linux even though I read the manual

Tags: tr

I try to understand what `-c` option does in `tr` command according to `man tr` command it says:

> -c, -C, --complement
>                use the complement of SET1

But I cannot understad what the doc mean by *"complement"* so I did the following example to understand it:

I created the following file named `trance.txt`:

```
ILOVE YOU
I HATE YOU
i WANNA EAT APPLE PIE
```

And I run: `tr -C A-Za-z "\n" < trance.txt`

That gives the output:

```
ILOVE
YOU
I
HATE
YOU
i
WANNA
EAT
APPLE
PIE
```

But I still do not get it what actually `-c` option does. Can you explain to me please?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It replaces the set `A-Za-z` with its complement, *i.e.* all the characters in the current character set, minus those specified. Quoting [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tr.html), in the absence of `-d`:

> - If the **-C** option is specified, the complements of the characters specified by *string1* (the set of all characters in the current character set, as defined by the current setting of *LC_CTYPE*, except for those actually specified in the *string1* operand) shall be placed in the array in ascending collation sequence, as defined by the current setting of *LC_COLLATE*.
> - If the **-c** option is specified, the complement of the values specified by *string1* shall be placed in the array in ascending order by binary value.

So your command is replacing all characters which *aren’t* A-Z or a-z with newlines.

Because [`tr` uses a one-to-one character map for its replacements](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/446031/86440), it’s not quite as simple as that; the `-c` and `-C` aren’t just “not in” options, they build the set of all characters which aren’t in the given set, in the order specified by the option. This is only relevant if the target set has more than one character.